# error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'std::function<void()>&' from an rvalue of type 'main()::<lambda()>'|

Tags: c++, rvalue, lvalue, lvalue-to-rvalue

**EDIT**: Sorry, I asked this question without a thro understanding of references...

I seem to be getting this error when I run this code...

**error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'std::function&' from an rvalue of type 'main()::'**

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std ;

void printfunction(bool a, function <void()> &b) 
{ 
    if (a == true) 
    {
        b() ; 
    }
} 

int main() 
{
    int value = 45 ;    

    printfunction(true, [value](){cout << "The value is : " << value ;}) ; 
}
```

But, the error **disappears** when I add a `const` before function... like this :

```
void printfunction(bool a,const function <void()> &b)
```

The thing is I would like to change the function in the function reference if needed... 
Is there any other way to do this? Please let me know if it does indeed exist.

Bye,

Samuel

Comment: C syntax error, C tag removed

Comment: Why aren't you taking the function by value then?

Comment: Something doesn't make sense here. If you change the function, the changes will be lost anyway since the caller creates a temporary function. So if you want to change the function in `printfunction`, you're calling it wrong. Do you want `printfunction` to get a private copy of the function that it can then modify without affecting its caller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `printfunction` call, lambda expression `[value]() {...}` argument must be converted to a temporary `function<void()>` object first.

A reference to non-const `function<void()>&` only binds to l-values, not temporaries (r-values).

A reference to const, on the other hand, can be bound to temporaries. Which is what you observe.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to modify the `std::function`, then you'll need to pass a modifiable (lvalue) parameter:

```
int main()
{
    int value = 45;

    std::function f = [value](){ std::cout << "The value is : " << value ;};

    printfunction(true, f);
}
```

What you were trying to do isn't much different from writing a function that takes a mutable reference to `int` (e.g. `void foo(int& x)`) and then complaining that you can't call `foo(5)`.  (The small difference is that the the lambda-expression is converted to a temporary `std::function` - but that still can't be bound to a non-const reference).

---

An alternative would be to change `printfunction` to take its argument *by value* rather than by reference, so that it has its own copy which it may modify.  You'll have to consider the needs of the caller to decide whether that's more appropriate.